# Prove that if the group is of odd size and $x^2=y^2$ then $x=y$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Prove that if the group is of odd size and $x^2=y^2$ then $x=y$. I can reduce the task to multiplicative group modulo even number, but I don't know what to do next

Comment: Hint: the order of every element of a group divides the order of the group (this is a consequence of [Lagrange's Theorem](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Lagrange%27s_theorem_(group_theory)#/Applications)

Comment: Sorry, I can't figure it out. I think, we can build a graph $x \to ax$, and this graph wouldn't have cycles of length 2 or even lengths?

Comment: Hint: Since the group has odd order, the map $x \mapsto x^2$ is surjective and hence injective.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Say $x$ has order $m$ and $y$ has order $n$. Then, $mn + 1$ is even (why?), so we can write $mn + 1 = 2k$. Now,
$$\begin{align}
x &= x^1\\
& = e^{\phantom{.}} x^1\\
& = e^n \, x^1\\
& = (x^m)^n x^1 \\
&= x^{mn+1}\\
& = x^{2k}\\
& = \bigl( x^2 \bigr)^k, 
\end{align}$$

and analogously, $y = \bigl( y^2 \bigr)^k$. Since $x^2 = y^2$, we may conclude that $x=y$.

Comment: Nice. This proof only requires that $x$ and $y$ have odd order, not the group.